# Android: ImageView Rotation Scale

Tags: android, bitmap, matrix, android-imageview

I have an imageView and I am basically trying to make a thermometer style gauge. I have added an image below for testing and I am basically trying to rotate the image. The first picture has the image in its standard layout. After trying to rotate the image, The width still fills the screen, but it scales the image down to make room for the corners, making the actual image appear smaller. I want the image to remain the exact same size, but rotate based on the Matrix passed to it.

[image: Normal Image]

[image: Image rotated incorrectly, for me anyways]

Here is the code I am using for the rotation:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        

    circle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rotated);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(45);

    Bitmap rot = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);

    circle.setImageBitmap(rot);        
}
```

So, I basically need the red/green circle edge to reach the edge of the screen. Is this possible with an imageView or will I need to write a custom view to allow stuff to be off screen? By the way, I am not actually gonna draw this whole circle, this is just an example to get my issue across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to calculate the actual new width and height.
try using some trigonometry

`newHeight = height/sin(alpha)`, where alpha is your rotation angle...

```
newWidth = width/cos(alpha)
```

then :

```
Bitmap rot = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight ,
            matrix, true);
```

not sure about the calculation, I didn't check it, but I think it correct, anyway, it's a great hint ;)

Comment: That's what I thought originally. The only problem is that when the size that I pass to createBitmap() is larger in width than the container, it force closes.

Comment: It hangs on createBitmap() or when it tries to put it in an imageView?

Comment: It force closes when it tries to put the new Bitmap into ImageView. Would it just be better to create a larger image, crop it, and then add it to the imageView (with the correct bounds)?

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer. The one below is kind of correct, but you both basically had the same answer. I think I like this implementation better. Thanks! If you can just add "crop final image based on scale" to your answer so future people can see it that would be great :)

Comment: @Rotemmiz I tried your code for rotating bitmap,that's fine,but for every rotation i lost the clarity of the image.Give me suggestions please...

Comment: Please post an image, and explain further, I can't understand the exact issue you have with no details, but I believe it has to do with aliasing...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that it is optimal but it work: just crop rotated bitmap to initial size.

```
circle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rotated);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(45);

Bitmap rot = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(), matrix, true);

int off = (rot.getWidth() - myImg.getWidth()) / 2;
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(rot, off, off, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight());

circle.setImageBitmap(result);
```